# Undefined Reference to glu in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting error on commands related to glu such as gluPerspective and gluLookAt when compiling. I am including in ***.pro** file:

```
QT += core gui opengl widgets declarative 
LIBS     += -lOpengl32
TARGET   = test
TEMPLATE = app
TEMPLATE = lib

SOURCES += main.cpp\
           mainwindow.cpp \
           glwidget.cpp 
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
            glwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    freeglut.dll \
    glew32.dll
```

in the **glwidget.h:**

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <QTimer>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //! CONSTRUCTOR
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //! DESTRUCTOR
    ~GLWidget();

protected:
    /// OPENGL
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();        

};
#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

**glwidget.cpp:**

```
 void GLWidget::paintGL() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective( 60.0, 1.0, 0.5, 10.0 );
        gluLookAt( 0.0, -1.8, 5.0, 0.0, -2.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    }
```

When getting the `gluPerspective` and `gluLookAt`, I am getting the error: undefined reference to 'gluPerspective@32' and undefined reference to 'gluLookAT@72'. Do you know what I am missing in the configuration to use the glu library?

Comment: Try `build->run qmake` and then rebuild

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to add:

```
LIBS += -lglut -lGLU
```

to your .pro file since `gluPerspective` comes from GLUT module.